# jQuery slideshow not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

I am trying to set up this Slideshow on my website. But for some reason is not working, even though I double checked endless times.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sShowGallery").css("overflow", "hidden");
    $("#sShow_nav").css("visibility", "visible");
    $("#sShow_nav a[href=#sld1]").addClass("active");

    $("#sShow_nav").localScroll({
        target:'#sShowGallery', axis: 'x'
    });

    $("#sShow_nav a").click(function(){
        $("#sShow_nav a").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});

<div id="sShow">
    <div id="sShowGallery">
        <ul>
            <li id="sld1"><a href="#image1"><img src="resource/images/sShow/igcbanner.png" width="900" height="350" alt="image1" /></a></li>
            <li id="sld2"><a href="#image2"><img src="resource/images/sShow/slider_002.jpg" width="900" height="350" alt="image2" /></a></li>
            <li id="sld3"><a href="#image3"><img src="resource/images/sShow/slider_003.jpg" width="900" height="350" alt="image3" /></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="sShow_nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#sld1"><img src="resource/images/sShow/igcbanner.png" width="900" height="350" alt="image1" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#sld2"><img src="resource/images/sShow/slider_002.jpg" width="900" height="350" alt="image2" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#sld3"><img src="resource/images/sShow/slider_003.jpg" width="900" height="350" alt="image3" /></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2VQ9A/

It only seems to be working on jsfiddle, its like its not being recognized by my browser or something weird.

This might be silly question and a simple answer. This is my first time working with Javascript.

I'll appreciate any help :)!

Comment: What about it is not working?

Comment: what is the error you are getting? You can see the javascript errors in the console panel of your browser.

Comment: can u show your imported js files

Comment: Did you include jquery?

Comment: Check what all javascripts were loaded SUCCESSFULLY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check on you page that you added the `jquery files` like:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

or add these files by any `CDN` like `Google` or `Microsoft`

Also Add you code after adding the above files
like:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    //your code
});
</script>
```

Comment: Have you added the code of `jQuery.LocalScroll plugin` in your `page` or `script`?

Comment: Silly me... I got to work using your 2nd example. Thanks alot. Btw I am using <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script> I added jQuery.LocalScroll plugin on the same page of my Slideshow.js.

Answer (score 0):

include these files

```
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

It is working in fiddle means definetely these are the probme.Try to include